# Is it possible to get a field through reflection without throwing an exception if it doesn't exist

Tags: java, reflection

If the statement below is called thousands of times, it will be very slow if there are many classes that do not have the a field named 'id'. Is there a way to get a field by name using reflection in java that will not throw an exception if the field does not exist?

```
Field f2 = null;
try{
    f2 = classThatMightNotHaveFieldId.getClass().getDeclaredField("id"); 
    f2.setAccessible(true);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(f1.get(classThatMightNotHaveFieldId));           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question about whether it is possible to find a field without an exception being thrown: yes, you can call `Class.getDeclaredFields()` to get all fields of the class, and then iterate through them to find one with the appropriate name:

```
for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
  if (field.getName().equals("id")) {
    // Do whatever.
    break;
  }
}
```

It should be noted that, whilst this doesn't throw an exception, it is not faster (and is often much slower) (by very crude micro-benchmarking) than just calling `class.getDeclaredField("id")` and swallowing the exception. `clazz.getDeclaredFields()` makes defensive copies of the fields before returning them, so there is quite a lot of additional work done when this method is invoked.

You haven't given details of your actual usage pattern in the question; you should maybe conduct some experiments to see whether the speedups can be achieved by alternative means with your existing implementation (like some sort of caching).

Comment: Also, it doesn't take a whole lot of work to build a simple caching system out of this, if we're trying to speed it up. Just keep a `Map<String, Field>` or `Map<Class<?>, Map<String, Field>>`, depending on what OP is doing. (`getDeclaredFields` creates an entire array for each call + iteration search.)

Comment: @Radiodef sure. That's just out of scope for the question.

Comment: Well, only sort of, because since they want to speed up their code, simply iterating `getDeclaredFields` is not an improvement. I was writing an answer to suggest this and decided to just post a comment since you got to it before me. Anyway, using `getDeclaredFields` and keeping a `Map` is the right solution.

Comment: @Radiodef I've done some tests, and found that `getDeclaredFields()` isn't any faster than exception swallowing. So I'm not convinced it is the "right" solution, just one that meets the criterion of not throwing an exception.

Comment: A `Map` is significantly faster than both, even only accounting for the fact that `getDeclaredField` also searches by iterating an array. Also, the difference depends on how many fields are declared. Of course we have no idea if OP actually needs this (possibly quite small) optimization.

Comment: This is the only solution that I have been able to find. But like you said, its not much faster. Unfortunately, adding a map to every class is not really an option .

Comment: Nobody said anything about adding a map to every class. You just need a map *somewhere* in which to cache the result of calling this method, so you only need to do evaluate it once for any given class.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the definition of `getDeclaredField()` method of Class below:

```
public Field getDeclaredField(String name) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
```

As per this, it can throw the above two exceptions. Now, have a look at the implementation:

```
if (field == null) {
    throw new NoSuchFieldException(name);
}
```

So, it will throw an exception of field is not found. If we want to suppress it then, we will have to use [FieldUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html#getField(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) class of Apache commons library which returns null if field is not found, e.g.:

```
class Test3{        
    private int field1;
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test3 test3 = new Test3();
        Field declaredField = FieldUtils.getDeclaredField(Test3.class, "field1", true);
        Field declaredField2 = FieldUtils.getDeclaredField(Test3.class, "field2", true);
        System.out.println(declaredField);
        System.out.println(declaredField2);
    }
}
```

This example prints hashCode for the first field and null for second field.

Comment: Looking at the [source code of `FieldUtils.getDeclaredField`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html) (line 167), it does basically the same as OP's code (maybe a little more). If OP's code is too slow, why is this going to be any faster?

Comment: OP wants to get the field without throwing an exception and my answer does solve the purpose.

Comment: No, an exception is still thrown; the library just catches and handles the exception. But OP's code already catches and handles the exception. So what advantage does adding this external dependency provide?

Comment: OP doesn't need to catch the exception explicitly. And that's what he wants.